# How do I disable the bootup sound on (TMO) Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a T-Mobile Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge that I would like to disable the bootup T-Mobile 'jingle'.  How do I disable this?

Comment: Have you tried turning down the volume on your phone before booting? Turning down the ringer volume did the trick for me since Android 2.3 (and does up until now on Android 5.1).

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You can use [**Silent Boot - Google Play**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antweb.silentboot&hl=en)

**2.** also you can do this with Root access and [**Root Explorer**](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=root%20explorer&c=apps&hl=en) :

```
Goto -> /system -> media -> audio -> ui
```

and rename this files :

> ```
> PowerOn.ogg 
> PowerOff.ogg
> ```

to something like this :

> ```
> PowerOn.ogg.disable
> PowerOff.ogg.disable
> ```

**but, there's not *non-root* method that guarantees silence the Startup sound.**

Comment: As this is my first Android phone, how exactly do I "root" my phone?

Comment: **how exactly do I "root" my phone?** : [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) this is another question! or ASK a new question please.